# How to remove {} from a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am writing code that will remove specific element if the user chooses to do so. It deletes the information in the brackets; but doesn't delete the brackets themselves. How to do it?

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for dict in data['songs']:
    if song in dict["SongName"]:
        songpath = (dict['Path'])

for stuff in data["songs"]:
    if song in stuff["SongName"]:
        del stuff["SongName"]
    if stuff["Path"]==songpath:
        del stuff["Path"]

with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ":"))
```

It returns:

```
"songs": [
    {},
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can filter out the content of `songs` easily with a list-comprehension:

```
data["songs"] = [song for song in data["songs"] if song]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check if `stuff` is empty. If so then delete that element from list:

```
!cat "/content/sample_data/test.json"
[Out]:
{
    "songs": [
        {
            "SongName": "a",
            "Path": "/home"
        }
    ]
}
```

```py
song = "a"

with open("/content/sample_data/test.json", 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)

for dict in data['songs']:
    if song in dict["SongName"]:
        songpath = (dict['Path'])

for stuff in data["songs"]:
    if song in stuff["SongName"]:
        del stuff["SongName"]
    if stuff["Path"]==songpath:
        del stuff["Path"]
    if len(stuff.keys()) == 0:
        data["songs"].remove(stuff)

with open("/content/sample_data/test_2.json", 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(data, fp,sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(",", ":"))
```

```
!cat "/content/sample_data/test_2.json"
[Out]:
{
    "songs":[]
}
```